# AsyncTask and JSOUP Parsing

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, jsoup

so basically im trying to parse some data from website using AsyncTask, i want it to get website url from program, update ui with downloaded data and show progressdialog (spinning wheel) so i figured i need to do it like that: (UPDATE): k now its ok with variables but program force closes anyway

```
private class backgroundDATA extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Document doc;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        dialog = dialog.show(Result.this, " ",
                " Loading. Please wait ... ", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();


        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        return null;
    }




protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


        Elements maine;
        Elements titleJSOUP;
        Elements recipeJSOUP;
        Elements instructionsJSOUP;

        String recipE;

        maine = doc.select("div#recipeContent");

        titleJSOUP = doc.select("title");

        recipeJSOUP = maine.select("ul.recipe");

        instructionsJSOUP = maine.select("p.instructions");



        recipE = recipeJSOUP.toString();


        drinkNameText.setText("THE "
                + Jsoup.parse(titleJSOUP.toString()).text()
                        );



        dontListenText.setText(Jsoup.parse(titleJSOUP.toString()).text()
                        );

        recipeText.setText(prepareDRINK(recipE));

        instructionsText.setText(Jsoup.parse(instructionsJSOUP.toString())
                .text());

        dialog.dismiss();


    }
```

}

Comment: Can't you just access the members of `backgroundDATA` during onPostExecute? main, doc, imgURL, etc?

Comment: it shows me that it cant be resolved as variable, declaring it outside this asynctask makes program force close

Comment: Are you sure it's the members such as `main` etc which can't be resolved? It seems more likely that it will be the UI elements such as `drinkNameText` which can't be resolved unless your `AsyncTask` is defined as an inner class in your `Activity`.

Comment: it is inner class defined in Result.java and called inside onCreate method, the code above in my opinion should work but with new backgroundDATA.execute(webiste) called it leads to force close

Answer (score 0):

Well this is going to cause a `NullPointerException` for a start...

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    dialog = dialog.show(Result.this, " ",
            " Loading. Please wait ... ", true);
}
```

You can't call `dialog.show(...)` as `dialog` will be `null`.

Call the static `ProgressDialog.show(...)` method instead.

Comment: Ok partially problem's solved - progress dialog appears but after a while it disappears and app leads to force close, also after that i can't see logcat in eclipse