# AsyncTasc in jsoup parser?

Tags: android, html, parsing, android-asynctask, jsoup

How to apply AsyncTasc in this example where using JSoup parser?Just i tried using Thread, but this not works starting with Android version 4.x.x. Maybe someone knows, how an example below, add AsyncTasc?
Thanks for advance.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class JSoupStudyActivity extends Activity {

// blog url
static final String BLOG_URL = "http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // set layout view
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // process
    try {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText(getBlogStats());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText("Error");
    }
}

protected String getBlogStats() throws Exception {
    String result = "";
    // get html document structure
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
    // selector query
    Elements nodeBlogStats = document.select("div#blog-stats ul li");
    // check results
    if(nodeBlogStats.size() > 0) {
        // get value
        result = nodeBlogStats.get(0).text();
    }

    // return
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short example:

```
public class JSoupStudyTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> // Check doc for explanation
{
     @Override
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls)
     {
          // Do your html parsing here
          // return your result or whatever
     }
}
```

There's a good example code here:

- [Parsing HTML in Android with Jsoup](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/04/parsing-html-in-android-with-jsoup.html)  (search for `AsyncTask`)
- [Android NetworkOnMainThreadException inside of AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398418/android-networkonmainthreadexception-inside-of-asynctask)
- [AsyncTask and JSOUP Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690519/asynctask-and-jsoup-parsing)

Also check the [AsyncTask documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), it has no jsoup example, but contains just everything you need to know to get it running.